# Use SQL to convert Datetime to w32time

Tags: sql, datetime, winapi

Does anyone know of a way using mirocsoft SQL to convert a date like "2014-10-31 00:00:00.000" to a format of w32time like "130592736000000000"?

Comment: well apparently (unconfirmed as yet) that number is a count of 100 nanosecond units since Jan 1, 1601 https://web.archive.org/web/20061107070716/http://www.jsifaq.com/SF/Tips/Tip.aspx?id=8079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!

```
SELECT CONVERT(bigint, DATEDIFF(DAY, '1600-12-31', '2014-10-31'))*24*60*60*10000000
```

*Edit
Fixed now